# exception- groovy connector : script is null

Tags: rest, groovy, bonita

I'm using Bonita BPM Community Edition v.7.0
In my process, I made a service task and it has a connector. I used Groovy 2.4 connector to call external Restful service.

This restful service url return the response as

```
{
  "RestResponse" : {
    "messages" : [ "More webservices are available at http://www.groupkt.com/post/f2129b88/services.htm", "Total [249] records found." ],
    "result" : [ {
      "name" : "Afghanistan",
      "alpha2_code" : "AF",
      "alpha3_code" : "AFG"
    }, {
      "name" : "Åland Islands",
      "alpha2_code" : "AX",
      "alpha3_code" : "ALA"
    }, {
      "name" : "Albania",
      "alpha2_code" : "AL",
      "alpha3_code" : "ALB"
    }, {
      "name" : "Algeria",
      "alpha2_code" : "DZ",
      "alpha3_code" : "DZA"
    }
}}
```

When I test at the Edit expression window using 'Evaluate' button, it works well.BUT.. when I test using 'Test' button, it prints as follows.

> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>   org.bonitasoft.engine.bpm.connector.ConnectorExecutionException: USERNAME=install | org.bonitasoft.engine.core.connector.exception.SConnectorException: org.bonitasoft.engine.connector.exception.SConnectorException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.bonitasoft.engine.connector.exception.SConnectorValidationException: org.bonitasoft.engine.connector.ConnectorValidationException: Error validating connector org.bonitasoft.connectors.scripting.GroovyScriptConnector:
>   The script is null.

My script is as follows,

```
@Grab(group='org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder', module='http-builder', version='0.7' )

import groovyx.net.http.RESTClient
//import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
//import groovy.json.JsonOutput

def client = new RESTClient( 'http://services.groupkt.com' )
def resp = client.get( path : '/country/get/all' ) // ACME boomerang

assert resp.status == 200  // HTTP response code; 404 means not found, etc.
def value= resp.getData()
def value1 = value.RestResponse.result

return value1[0].name
```

Response like: Afghanistan

while test it, Why it shows that error?
Any one please help me out from this issue,

Answer (score 0):

It was a bug. Fixed in 7.3.1.

Best